# Как получить data из vue компонента в другом компоненте?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть vue royter

```
.....
const Edit = Vue.component('edit', require('./components/pages/edit.vue'));
const Product_category = Vue.component('home',             
require('./components/pages/product_categories.vue'));

const routes = [
........
{
    path: '/product_categories',
    name: 'product_categories',
    component: Product_category
},
{
    path: '/product_categories/edit/:id',
    name: 'product_categories_edit',
    components: {default: Edit, entity: Product_category},
    props: {default: true, entity: true}
}
];
```

Как я могу получить data компонета Product_category в компонете Edit?

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['id', 'entity'],
    mounted: function () {
        console.log('Admin edit page mounted.');
        console.log(this.entity); // Eror
        console.log(entity); // Eror
        this.getData();
    },
}
</script>
```

Прямое обращение не подходит, т.к. у каждого роута будет свой entity.

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Коммуникация-между-компонентами-не-связанными-иерархически

Comment: смотри в сторону Vuex